# ADF pipelines not able to run on self hosted integration runtime

Tags: azure-storage, azure-data-factory

We have Azure Data Factory V2 pipeline, consuming data from on-prem SQL Server, Pipelines was running perfectly fine until 2 weeks. 2 weeks back it started running very slow (15min vs 2h:15min).
So today we tried to restart the machine which installed IR. After that pipeline started giving an error:

> Unable to load DLL 'jvm.dll': The specified module could not be found.

We have verify everything mentioned in [post](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4497239/hresult-0x8007007e-error-when-you-run-a-copy-activity-to-azure).

Then we have reinstalled the Integration Runtime on the machine and now pipelines keep running without transferring data. All the pipelines lies in the queue. There is no activity we can see on IR Monitor. Pipelines are not sending any request to IR.

Comment: Is this the case even when you re-install Azure IR and JRE on your on-premises data gateway?

Comment: Try a clean install. Uninstall the IR and the JRE, then install JRE, then IR.

Comment: after reinstalling both it worked properly

Answer (score 0):

Sharing the answer as per the comment by the original poster:

Able to resolve the issue by reinstalling JRE and integration runtime.

Try a clean install. Uninstall the IR and the JRE, then install JRE, then IR.